# Sendgrid, Rails application, Mailer and Heroku configuring email the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

Hi I am building a feature where upon signing up, the user can receive an outbound email to their email box thanking them for singing up.

This is my first time configuring email on my rails application.

As far as I know I need to

1. generate a mailer
2. pass in the user model and user.email to my mailer.rb
3. write the signup confirmation.txt template generated in the view
4. call the mailer.signup.delivery method and pass in the user model in the controller

all from this railscast, http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email-revised

hopefully I got the ideas right can someone confirm,

I am more worried about implementing sendgrid and heroku, currently I am waiting for my sendgrid provision to finish. (I just signed up)

from sendgrid api, i need to paste this into my environment.rb to enable sendgrid

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port           => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'heroku.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

add the sendgrid add on onto heroku (I did that) and set the sengrid username and password on heroku according to the heroku sendgrid docs.

Am I doing this correctly? the last time I configured ssl on heroku, the docs were wrong and I ended up spending two days on a couple of tutorials. before I go ahead and mess with my application

can someone confirm I am doing this correctly?

Comment: This is correct. Also what is the worst that could happen? You should always test it locally first anyway, or create a (free) staging server on heroku.

Comment: You actually don't need to wait for a SendGrid provision if you're a heroku customer and want to use their addons.  Simply run "heroku addons:add sendgrid:starter" from your terminal and you should be good to go.  Your setup sounds correct though.

Comment: @jokklan what is a free staging server? its true probably nothing bad will happen but I like to know totally what I am doing before implementing, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Swift my sendgrid account said email won't work yet because the provision is not done yet that is all.

Comment: A staging server is a server that have the same setup as your production server but is not open to public. You often setup a staging environment in your rails app, a environment between deveopment and production. As a staging server only is for you, can you use one of heroku's free servers for this. You can see more here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/72-adding-an-environment-revised

Comment: @jngai1297 email your username to "swift@sendgrid.com" and I will provision you

Comment: Is there an actual question, here?